# Getting "expected string or bytes-like object" for a python for loop

Tags: string, for-loop, python-3.5, tokenize

This is the code i am trying to run.

```
src_doc = open("set1_neg.txt", 'rb')
words = []

for line in src_doc.readlines():
 words.append(line)
 user_input= word_tokenize(words)
print(words)
```

But, i keep getting this error. 
[image]

P.S This may be a question with a simple answer. I couldn't figure it out may be because i am new to python.

Comment: try this`for index in range(len(words)):
   print 'Current word:', words[index]` instead of `print(words)`

Comment: The error is not for how i print the words

Comment: opps sorry. I think the word_tokenize() method expects a string your passing it an array.